# Error -11800 when attempting to insertTimeRange of AVComposition to AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avfoundation, avcomposition

I'm working with `AVFoundation` using audio only - i.e. no video - and trying to join several `AVComposition`s together, one after the other, to end up with one single `AVComposition`.

Example case: just two `AVComposition`s. Each of them plays fine by creating an AVPlayer thus:

```
_player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:comp]]
```

where `comp` is an instance of `AVMutableComposition`. (Incidentally, it's worth noting that `_player` has to be an ivar otherwise ARC prematurely releases it before it plays - took a while to track that one down.)

That's good - executing

```
[_player play]
```

results in `comp` being played back successfully.

However, this fails:

(`self.segments` is an `NSMutableArray` containing elements that are a custom subclass of `AVMutableComposition`)

```
AVMutableComposition *comp = [AVMutableComposition composition];
NSError *err;
for (AVMutableComposition* c in self.segments) {
    [comp insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, segment.duration)      
                  ofAsset:segment atTime:comp.duration error:&err];
    DLog(@"Error was %@", segment, err);
}
```

For every element of `self.segments` when this code executes, I get this error when invoking the `insertTimeRange::::` method:

```
Error was Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not
be completed" UserInfo=0x14e8e7f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be 
completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x14d7f580 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus 
error -12780.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780)}
```

I can't find any information about what this error indicates - seems to be just a catch-all - and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I've just tried using a for loop and objectAtIndex: instead of fast enumeration over the self.segments NSMutableArray and it's no different.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I am running into a very similar issues (with video however, not just audio - error numbers are also slightly different `AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11801`, and `(OSStatus 
error -12786.)`)

Comment: try to use  :fileURLWithPath instead of :urlwithstring

Answer (score 2):

This code error corresponds to `AVErrorUnknown = -11800` so there is not much explanation about the cause of the issue. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/averror/averrorunknown?language=objc

Just in case it might help somebody else I'll point out here my reason.

**Context**

In my case, I was getting the error when trying to connect to Airplay.

**Cause**

The cause was that I have 2 instances of AVPlayer. One for a movie type video and another one for a preview. Then when I was trying to cast the movie... AVFoundation was getting confused and it was delivering this error.

**Solution**

On the `moviePlayback` instance:

```
allowsExternalPlayback = true
usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true
```

On the `default` instance:

```
allowsExternalPlayback = false
usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = false
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `CMTimeRange` was wrong and duration == 0. This is because `CMTimeMake` will convert the input to an integer and it loses precision.

To solve this problem, I used a bigger time scale.

Problem code:

```
CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake(timeStamp.begin, 1);
CMTime duration = CMTimeMake(timeStamp.duration, 1);
```

Right code:

```
CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake(timeStamp.begin*1000, 1000);
CMTime duration = CMTimeMake(timeStamp.duration*1000, 1000);
```

then it works properly.

```
[videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, duration) ofTrack:videoTracks.firstObject atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `segment.asset` is not released. So if the condition `segment.asset == nil` is true, the media data behind is gone, so the insert action failed.

ref: https://www.jianshu.com/p/089f6691dbdb (at bottom of the article)